# How do I amend the have_posts function to include custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme

I'm building a child theme and have set up an additional custom post type ('blogs').

I need regular and custom posts to be returned on the archive page. The have_posts function only returns regular posts.

How do I amend the have_posts function to include custom posts?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
    endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

I did try this approach:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'blogs' ),
);  
$myQuery = new WP_Query($args);
    
if ($myQuery->have_posts() ) : 
    while ($myQuery->have_posts() ) :
    $myQuery->the_post();
    endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

Which returned posts and 'blogs' - but from ALL categories, instead of posts and 'blogs' with the relevant category.

Any advice would be much appreciated as I'm new to Wordpress dev.

Comment: `have_posts` doesn't perform the query, take a look at the `pre_get_posts` filter

Comment: Can you make it clear that which relevant category are you referring? Post type and categories are different things in WordPress.

Comment: Hi - I mentioned categories because I want the archive page to show both types of posts - when a link to a Category is clicked.

Comment: Thanks to Tom for suggesting the pre_get_posts hook. 

this partially solved the issue:
https://wpshout.com/practical-uses-pre_get_posts/
```
function display_custom_posts_on_archives( $query ) {
 if( 
  is_archive() &&
  empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )
 ) {
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 
   'post',
   'blogs'
  ) );
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_custom_posts_on_archives' );
```

However, now my custom post archive page and the custom post backend now shows ALL posts rather than just custom posts.